# MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I know this question was asked many times before. However all the answers I found didn't help.
I'm trying to include a resource bundle in a simple Marven project. I did put it into the `resources` folder. I did put it everywhere else, all other possible locations files can exist, really everywhere (except the moon), doesn't help. The file is called `xxx_en_US.properties` the original `xxx.properties` it was generated by NetBeans itself. I deleted the files, regenerated them, renamed them, nothing helps.
The autogenerated code by NetBeans reads `java.util.ResourceBundle bundle = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("xxx");`
and the exception is `java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name xxx, locale en_US`. It's a simple project I just started from scratch, so a simple NetBeans Maven template nothing else that could somehow conflict, the bundle has just one single entry.

[image]

This is one of the locations `src/main/resources` I tried. I also tried `src/resources` and so on.

Comment: Would you please share screenshot of project, that might helpful to understand.

Comment: try: `ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(".xxx");` Notice the dot.

Comment: Is this a project with the Swing GUI editor ? Then the properties must go into a folder tree (below ./resources)  that is the same as the package of your GUI class.

Comment: @PeterMmm do you mean com/abc/projectName and so on? And the resources folder itself into src/main?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.